# How do you filter a dataframe to make sure values in two columns differ in Pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to compare two tables with the same columns and then return columns that conflict. For example:
Table A:

| emp_id | emp_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Mary |

Table B:

| emp_id | emp_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Karen |
| 3 | Steve |

In this instance, I want to know that two different names conflict for 2. I do not care that there is an entry in one table that is not in the other, and I don't care if the entry is in both tables if they do not conflict.

So far my approach was to rename the columns as emp_name1 & 2, join the tables and then filter out null values meaning the name only appears in one list this way:

```
df = df.join(df2, how = 'outer', on = ['emp_id'])
#filter out null vals (meaning no conflict)
df = df.filter((df.emp_name1.isNotNull()) &(df.emp_name2.isNotNull()))
```

The next step would be to compare the values to see if they are the same, but when I try to do this, it does not work:
`df = df.filter((df.emp_name1 = df.emp_name2))`

Is there a way to compare columns to each other in this way?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: My desired output for these two tables would be:

2           | Mary             | Karen

Answer (score 0):

```
combined_df = pd.concat([df, df2])
print(combined_df[combined_df.duplicated()])
```

Output:

```
   emp_id emp_name
0       1     John
```

Or, since I'm not exactly sure what you're asking;

```
print(combined_df[~combined_df.duplicated()])
...
   emp_id emp_name
0       1     John
1       2     Mary
1       2    Karen
2       3    Steve
```

```
print(combined_df[~combined_df.duplicated(keep=False)])
...
   emp_id emp_name
1       2     Mary
1       2    Karen
2       3    Steve
```

Comment: If you want to use `.duplicated()` on a subset, you can specify it such as: `df.duplicated('emp_name')`

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables on emp id as you have already done. Then use where otherwise clause to check if there is conflict.
Assuming col name after joining as : emp_id,
emp_name_1 and
emp_name_2

```
final_df= df.withColumn("conflict_names", when(col("emp_name_1")!=col("emp_name_2"), col("emp_name_2")).otherwise(lit(None).cast(StringType())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last filter condition is incorrect `df = df.filter((df.emp_name1 = df.emp_name2))`. It should be

```py
df = df.filter((df.name1 != df.name2))

+---+-----+-----+
| id|name1|name2|
+---+-----+-----+
|  2| Mary|Karen|
+---+-----+-----+
```